# Show message in "post answer" box for new users

Tags: feature-request, answers, new-users

It's quite common for new users to "answer" a question by posting.

> Yes, I have the same problem. Could you fix it?

I'm suggesting that we add some default text to the answer box like "Type your answer here. Please only add solutions. Do not post just to say you are having the same problem" for users with less than a certain amount of rep (50 sounds good).

Similar to the Search default text, this would disappear when clicked on so as not to be too disruptive.

This [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/57072/unable-to-use-tweetdeck-on-windows-due-to-ooops-tweetdeck-cant-find-your-data) is quite bad (4 "me too" answers).

I know we can flag these, but that adds extra works for the moderators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I completely understand, unfortunately, we also restrict the user's ability to upvote or to comment, so these are essentially upvotes and comments saying, please help.

I think your solution is alright, but I don't think that it will actually resolve the problem, people tend to ignore these sorts of things.

Comment: There's a cartoon site I visit that gets members to post punchlines. Even with "NOT FOR PUNCHLINES" on the background of comment boxes and *** NOT FOR PUNCHLINES *** above the box and "(but not if its a punchline)" next to the "Submit" button, people still submit punchlines.

Comment: Even as a comment "me too" is not very useful...